# Use flex wrap with stretch elements as rows

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to use `flex-wrap` and `stretch` with little success. Everything looks good as long as window width is less than height. But as soon as I resize the screen, 2 rows become 1.

[image: Example]

I'm planning to use flex to display any amount of images, mostly with 16:9 dimensions. So, it would be great to make the layout more row-ish instead of column-ish. Thanks!

```css
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: stretch;
    align-content: stretch;
    justify-content: center;
    position: fixed;
}

.item {
    min-width: 100px;
    min-height: 100px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
.item:nth-child(1){
  background: red;
}
.item:nth-child(2){
  background: green;
}
.item:nth-child(3){
  background: blue;
}
.item:nth-child(4){
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe you could provide html

Comment: There is a div with `container` class and 4 divs with `item` class inside

Comment: you could use css grid instead if you're going for a gallery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To correct your code *(The second method will be more responsive on small screen)*:

- Either just add `width: 50%;` to `.item`, as in first demo below.
- Either just modify `min-width: 100px` to `min-width: 50%;`

But I would recommand you to use `display:grid;` as in second Demo (code is much more simple.

### DEMO based on your code:

```css
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: stretch;
    align-content: stretch;
    justify-content: center;
    position: fixed;
}

.item {
    min-width: 100px;
    min-height: 100px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
    flex-grow: 1;
    width: 50%;
}
.item:nth-child(1){
  background: red;
}
.item:nth-child(2){
  background: green;
}
.item:nth-child(3){
  background: blue;
}
.item:nth-child(4){
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

### DEMO based with grid:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
}
.item {
  min-width: 100px;
  min-height: 100px;
}
.item:nth-child(1){
  background: red;
}
.item:nth-child(2){
  background: green;
}
.item:nth-child(3){
  background: blue;
}
.item:nth-child(4){
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>  
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've ended up using the grid approach you suggested. One small change: I don't actually want to limit amount of columns to 2, so I've made it `grid-template-columns: auto auto auto` and now it works great.